# Is the phrase "Ars gratia physicae" correct?

Tags: translation-check

Is the phrase "*ars gratia physicae*" correct? What does it mean? Could it mean "Art for physics' sake"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed correct.
*X[nom] gratia Y[gen]* is a common way to say "X for the sake of Y".
X has to be in nominative and Y in genitive.
For *ars* and *physica* they are *ars* and *physicae*.

You could also use the Greek variant *physice* for physics, and the genitive would be *physices*.
The standard Latin variant *physicae* is easier to understand.
(The way this works is as follows: The word *physica* is an adjective used here without a noun. See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11443/79) for details. An adjective is always treated as a fully Latin word, so the Greek style declension is out of the question. However, the same happens in Greek, where the adjective *φυσική* alone can mean "physics". The Greek variant would be a direct borrowing of that substantivized Greek adjective, not of a plain adjective.)

The word *gratia* often comes after the genitive it works with.
The phrase at hand is modeled after *ars gratia artis* or a variant thereof, and the analogy is kept strongest by keeping the original structure.
A more typical way to put it in classical Latin would be *ars physicae gratia*.

Comment: Would you use _physicē_ here? I would have thought _physica_, neuter plural, like in the Latin title of Aristotle's work.

Comment: @Draconis I might, but I'd mostly use *physica*. I've only ever seen *physica* as a singular feminine, and the Greek variant makes sense as it appears to be a calque of the Greek *physice techne*. It is an adjective, so a plural *physica* as in "physical things" makes sense for a title in Aristotle, but that to me is different than physics as a field.

Comment: Does gratia ever precede the genitive that goes with it? At any rate, it's more usual to put it after.

Comment: @cnread *Ars gratia artis* is an expression many others are modeled after. I agree that *gratia* often comes after the genitive, for a simple maxim like "X for the sake of Y" this is common. But not the only choice. I'll edit a bit.

Comment: Right, I forgot about ars gratia artis. And a quick peak in OLD has just told me that, even in classical usage, although of gratia placement after the genitive is usual, it isn't the only possibility.

Comment: Perhaps pedantic, but for Aristotle physics (or, to capture the meaning of the term better, "natural science") was most certainly an ἐπιστήμη, not a τέχνη. I'm also pretty skeptical of "physice, -es" as a Latin borrowing: both Aquinas and Descartes use "physica" as a feminine singular.

Comment: Φυσικὴ is, at least originally, an abbreviation of Aristotle's book title  Φυσικὴ ἀκρόασις "the lecture about natural things".

Comment: @fdb Even within the *Physics*, Aristotle frequently uses φυσική alone (to designate the science) or as an adjective, so I don't think you should see the term as a mere abbreviation.